# VisualSVN Server 2.5.2 reports "413 Request Entity Too Large" when attempting to commit multigigabyte files

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, apache-1.3

I'm getting the following error, when attempting to commit large files (multi-gigabyte) to a new local installation of VisualSVN 2.5.2 Server on a Windows XP machine.

> "413 Request Entity Too Large"

I'm using Windows authentication, and I've already added the following settings (and then restarted the server) to httpd-custom.conf:

```
LimitXMLRequestBody 0
LimitRequestBody 0
```

If it matters, I'm using TortoiseSVN as a client.

Is there something else that needs to be done to get VisualSVN Server to accept large files?

**Update**:

Contents of the SVNServer Event Viewer:

> 1/13/2012 3:31:45 PM  VisualSVN Server 2.5    Error   Apache 1001 CORP\sam.johnson    IOMFOX0960L Could not get next bucket brigade [500, #0] [client 10.155.60.53]
>       1/13/2012 3:31:45 PM  VisualSVN Server 2.5    Error   Apache  1001 CORP\sam.johnson   IOMFOX0960L Invalid Content-Length [client 10.155.60.53]

Comment: Can you check what's recorded in the Apache error log when this occurs?

Comment: I've updated my question with the Apache Errors. Thanks for the recommendation, I'll start researching them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting an error on this chunk of validation code, in `http_filters.c`:

```c
/* Protects against over/underflow, non-digit chars in the
 * string (excluding leading space) (the endstr checks)
 * and a negative number. */
if (apr_strtoff(&ctx->remaining, lenp, &endstr, 10)
    || endstr == lenp || *endstr || ctx->remaining < 0) {

    ctx->remaining = 0;
    ap_log_rerror(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_ERR, 0, f->r,
      "Invalid Content-Length");

    return bail_out_on_error(ctx, f, HTTP_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
}
```

So, your removal of the request body limit was successful.  It looks like the client is at fault; Tortoise seems to be be sending invalid data in the `Content-Length` header.  Is there any way that you can capture the full HTTP request (it'll need to be unencrypted http, and you'll need a capture tool like wireshark) to inspect what it's sending in that header?

Comment: Looks like the client (TortoiseSVN) is sending an negative value for some reason. There's a few threads about it here and there, but no resolution that I've been able to find. Should I leave this question up, or take it down and post a more specific question (since it's the client's issue, not the server)

Comment: Well, first thing is that I'd recommend is to seriously reconsider storing multi-gig files in SVN.. it's really not made for that.  That said, it looks like the neon library is the cause, and switching to serf may resolve it - see [here](https://groups.google.com/group/subversion_users/browse_thread/thread/cea04dc4694ba64a).

Comment: Good call - that's exactly what it was, and confirmed by VisualSVN Server support as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**"413 Request Entity Too Large"** error on commit is rather a client's
issue than the server's one.

Subversion clients use ***neon*** library for network communication by default.
This library does not support transmission large files to Subversion
server correctly.

As a workaround you can switch from ***neon*** to ***serf*** library.
Perform the steps on client's machine:

1. Open file `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers`
2. Find `[global]` section
3. Add following option to the `[global]` section: `http-library=serf`
4. Save servers file and try to commit again

Comment: This answer is also correct - I accepted the above one for including the explanation that confirmed that it was a client issue. Thanks for your input!